# Hive union all performance

Tags: hadoop, hive, union-all

If I have two queries that are querying data from the same table but each group by different column. Then I should use two separated queries or use the `union all` function? My concern is about performance. Because I some people said `union all` should be avoided if not necessary, otherwise it's a big overhead.

For example, should I use `UNION ALL` for below queries? Please advise. Thanks.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE newtable
SELECT SUBSTRING(A1, 1, 7) AS col1, COUNT(DISTINCT B) AS col2, C AS col3
FROM oldtable
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(A1, 1, 7), C;

INSERT INTO TABLE newtable
SELECT A2 AS col1, COUNT(DISTINCT B) AS col2, C AS col3
FROM oldtable
GROUP BY A2, C;
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a `UNION ALL` whose parents are 2 MapReduce jobs.
Each MapReduce job will write its output to temporary files, and then the `UNION` will read these temporary files and write to your final storage. So as you can see it's very wasteful because you end up reading and writing the results twice !

There are [some improvements](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Union+Optimization) that have been done as part of Hive 0.10 so you could give it a try if you're running one of the newer versions.

Comment: Thanks @Charles. Would you please give me some hints on what do "file sink" and "parent" mean here?